# how to keep original ratio of image within square div

Tags: css

I have seen lot of solution about this. The solutions are either for wider or taller image. But my problem is the image which need to keep in ratio, I have no idea it could be taller or wider.

Comment: It would help if you provide some of your code, or an example of the scenarios you refer to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just give it `width: 100%` to make it *responsive* or adjustable to the *parent's* size:

```css
.square {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%; /* also make its parent responsive (advisable) */
}

.square > img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace, alternative: "vertical-align: bottom" */
  width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x900" alt="img">
</div>
```